# Keeping a webpage alive/afk

Tags: python, http

I wanted to make a request to the website. But it closes after the request ends. I want to be afk/keep alive forever. Like beeing afk on chrome. But i am using Repl.it.

I just want to keep alive the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session = requests.Session()` and do all of your requests via that `session`, for example with `session.get()` or `session.post()`.